# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "qGumbel"

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I am relatively new to R and trying to simulate a Gumbel copula with and one of these margin is gumbel pdf and the other is exponential.

by this code

```
G3 <- gumbelCopula(1.37, dim=2)
gMvd2 <- mvdc(G3, c("Gumbel","exp"), param = list(list(shape=10.2988298881251, scale=1.02463492397923), list(rate=4)))
set.seed(11)
# n <- if(Xtras) 10000 else 200 # sample size (realistic vs short for example)
x <- rMvdc(100, gMvd2)
head(x)
```

The output was:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "qGumbel"
Traceback:

1. rMvdc(100, gMvd2)
2. eval(qdf.expr, list(x = u[, i]))
3. eval(expr, envir, enclos)
```

They also mention remark

Warning message in mvdCheckM(margins, "p"):

```
"margins correct? Currently, have no function(s) named: pGumbel"Warning message in mvdCheckM(margins, "d"):
"margins correct? Currently, have no function(s) named: dGumbel"
```

I think the problem lies in  parameter values of the marginal distributions because when I type

```
G3 <- gumbelCopula(1.37, dim=2)
gMvd2 <- mvdc(G3, c("exp","exp"), param = list(list(rate=2), list(rate=4)))
set.seed(11)
# n <- if(Xtras) 10000 else 200 # sample size (realistic vs short for example)
x <- rMvdc(100, gMvd2)
head(x)
```

No problem!!

Comment: Try lowercase G. http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/ActuDistns/html/qgumbel.html

Comment: tried it did not work also, therefore, I think I will have to code the function myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Elin mentioned in the comment I did it by changing capital G to small g and added my own function

```
qgumbel <- function(p,shape,scale) shape-scale *log(-log(p))
```

and now the code works

```
G3 <- gumbelCopula(1.37, dim=2)
gMvd2 <- mvdc(G3, c("gumbel","exp"), param = list(list(shape=10.2988298881251, scale=1.02463492397923), list(rate=4)))
set.seed(11)
# n <- if(Xtras) 10000 else 200 # sample size (realistic vs short for example)
x <- rMvdc(100, gMvd2)
head(x)
#  parameter values of the marginal distributions
```